# I am working in C and Trying to invert the char of string such as 'a to z', 'z to a', 'b to y', 'y to b' and so on

Tags: c, string

I am getting correct output for when the string length is odd such as 5,9 and so on , but in case of even numbers it is printing one extra character I am not getting why it is happening. Can anyone help me with my code that where I am doing wrong.

**test case 1:** ranus **here n=5 which is odd**

**op1 :** iamfh **which is correct**

**testcase2 :** ranu **here n=4 which is even**

**op2:** iamf@ **which is Incorrect**

> Adding my code here

```
#include <stdio.h>
char revert(char c){
char a[26]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char b[26]="zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
    if(a[i]==c){
       c=b[i];
    }
}
return c;
}
int main(void) {
int t,n,s;
scanf("%d",&t);
for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char a[n],b[n];
    scanf("%s",a);
    char temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i=i+2){
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[i+1];
        a[i+1]=temp;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        char d= revert(a[i]);
        b[i] = d ;
    }
    printf("%s",a);
    printf("\n%s",b);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u define it more precisely It will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a "substitution cipher".

```
char *cipherStr ="zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";

for( int i = 0; inStr[ i ] != '\0'; i++ ) {
    outStr[ i ] = inStr[ i ];
    if( islower( outStr[ i ] ) )
        outStr[ i ] = cipherStr[ outStr[ i ] - 'a' ];
}
```

The `- 'a'` uses the ASCII value of the (lowercase) source letter to make an index into the char array 'cipherStr'.

Given the two examples, 'swapping pairs of characters' makes no sense to me.

Comment: Sir This is the question on which I was working on check rules of the question link : https://www.codechef.com/submit/ENCMSG

Comment: Okay, I read the challenge. "Swapping letter pairs" is part of the problem statement. "Going wrong?" You use 'a[]' and 'b[]' as buffers to store 'n' characters, but do not account for the required '\0' at the end of a C string. Declare `char a[ n+1 ]'` and be sure to properly terminate `b[]` before sending it off to `printf()`.